# Wikipedia | ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: python, django, urllib2, wikipedia

I am trying to get a page from wikipedia. I have already added a 'User-Agent' header to my request. However, when I open the page using urllib2.urlopen I get the following page as a result:
        
        ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved

## ERROR

### The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL the following error was encountered:

- **Access Denied.**

  Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Here is the code I use to open the page:

```
def get_site(request_user_link,request):                                                    # request_user_link is request for url entered by user
                                                                                            # request is request generated by current page - used to get HTTP_USER_AGENT
                                                                                            # tag for WIKIPEDIA and other sites
    request_user_link.add_header('User-Agent',str(request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request_user_link)
    except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
        logger.error('HTTPError = ' +str(err.code))
        response=None
    except urllib2.URLError, err:
        logger.error('HTTPError = ' +str(err.reason))
        response=None
    except httplib.HTTPException, err:
        logger.error('HTTPException')
        response=None
    except Exception:
        import traceback
        logger.error('generic exception' + traceback.format_exec())
        response=None
    return response
```

I pass the value of the HTTP_USER_AGENT from the current user object as the "User-Agent" header for the request I send to wikipedia. 
If there are any other headers I need to add to this request, please let me know. Otherwise, please advise an alternate solution.

**EDIT: Please note that I was able to get the page successfully yesterday after I added the 'User-Agent' header. Today, I seem to be getting this Error page.**

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: No I am not behind a proxy server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is not very forgiving if violate their [crawling rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt). As you first exposed your IP with the standard urllib2 user-agent you were branded in the logs. When the logs were 'processed' your IP was banned. This should be easily tested by running your script for another IP. Be careful since Wikipedia is also known to block IP ranges.

IP bans are usually temporary, but if you have multiple offenses it *can* become permanent.

Wikipedia also have autoban on known proxy servers. I suspect that they are them selves parsing anon proxy sites like [proxy-list.org](http://proxy-list.org/en/index.php) and commercial proxy sites like [hidemyass.com](http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/) for the IP's.

Wikipedia does this of course to protect the content from vandalism and spam. Please respect the rules.

If possible I suggest the use of a [local copy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download) of wikipedia on your own servers. This copy you can violate to your harts content.

Answer (score 1):

i wrote a script that reads from wikipedia, this is a simplified version.

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')] #wikipedia needs this    
resource = opener.open(URL)
data = resource.read()
resource.close()
#data is your website.
```

Comment: if your code was aggressive - wikipedia may have blocked your IP. check if you can manually browse wikipedia.

Comment: I can browse wikipedia. The link I was trying to access is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali_Jinnah which is now blocked. Similarly I cannot access the pages http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ali (there is no link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinnah so I couldnt try it). I cannot open these pages in the browser or ping them. However, I can access other pages from wikipedia (so I assume my IP is not blocked). I have taken this problem with my internet service provider as well to check if the pages were blocked from their end for some reason.

Comment: Please also note that I can open other wikipedia pages using this code as well (for now at least). Only the above links seem to be blocked from wikipedia which makes it a little more peculiar.

Comment: i can access http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali_Jinnah no problem. must be something strange going on. i have no idea what to tell you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep you posted. I just want to check if they blocked these tags (Muhammad, Ali and Jinnah) from my IP specifically and if so, is there any other workaround :). Thanks again

Comment: Please, don't try to impersonate a browser. Instead, you should use a [custom User-Agent with some contact information](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy).